# Rails add a lightbox to an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox2

Rails 4.
Hi I d'like to add an lightbox to my application. I have follow the step-by-step instructions for [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) but my photo gallery doesn't respond at all

I have called (:all : application) the file necessary in my application.html.erb. My view is ok I think the problem reside in my way to call the vendor files.

I place all the lightbox files under `vendor/assets/javascript` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets` respectively. I did create an vendor/assets/images for the Lightbox images file (close icon...) and my application.html.erb contains:

```
stylesheet_link_tag    "application",  media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

Nothing show up properly concerning my photo-gallery. any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `/assets/javascripts/application.js` add this line after `//= require jquery`:

```
//= require lightbox-2.6.min
```

same thing for your `/assets/stylesheets/application.js` add this line :

```
//= require lightbox
```

Comment: no I still have an issue with this. Cause the lightbox effect doesn't appears like it sould be.

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho what is the problem ?

Comment: lightbox.css and lightbox-2.6.min.js are charge properly on the <header> but  not my img folder cause. I do have the lightbox effect on my pictures but I don't have the X or the > Foward button anymore. (my gist::https://gist.github.com/guinslym/8233045)

Comment: i think you are placed images in a folder, and your css file point to another place then can't find your images , is this the problem ?

Comment: Yeah this was the problem now I fixed it. Thks medBo

Answer (score 1):

I added the following line that @medBo told me too.

But for the IMG folder I placed it inside the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

add '.scss' to the lightbox.css file and edit
line 195 to 'background: url(/img/close.png) top right no-repeat;' 
then you can keep the img folder inside the assets folder where it belongs if you are going to compile assets localy

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can take a look at these gems:

> [Lightbox Rails](https://github.com/gavinkflam/lightbox2-rails)
>
> [Lightbox for Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/luciuschoi/lightbox-bootstrap-rails)